# please share the code for Calendar or Date picker (Popup) in JavaScript to implement in JSF

Tags: javascript, calendar

please share the code for Calendar or Date picker (Popup) in JavaScript to implement in JSF

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) – open source. Free download :)

Answer (score 0):

[The “Coolest” DHTML Calendar](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/) - I like it for the menu when you hold arrows. Very useful for picking some older dates.